# Extending a generic implementer class

Tags: java, generics

I have a `DAO` object that I'd normally extend with the entity class name like so:

```
public class DAO<T> {

    private final Class<T> clazz;
    public DAO(Class<T> clazz {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}

public class EntityDAO extends DAO<Entity> {

    public EntityDAO() {
        super(Entity.class);
    }
}
```

However, I have some abstract entities that I would like to create an abstract DAO that gets implemented into a concrete class later on:

```
public class DAO<T> {

    private final Class<T> clazz;
    public DAO(Class<T> clazz {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractEntityDAO extends DAO<T extends AbstractEntity> {

    public AbstractEntityDAO () {
        super(AbstractEntity.class);
    }
}

public abstract class EntityDAO extends AbstractEntityDAO <Entity> {

    public EntityDAO() {
        super(Entity.class);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work as the `AbstractEntityDAO` complains about an unexpected bound and it cannot resolve T. Is it possible to do this? And if so, how is it written?

This is using Java 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the generic type definition on `AbstractEntityDAO`:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntityDAO<T extends AbstractEntity> extends DAO<T> {
...
}
```

With your current code `AbstractEntityDAO <Entity>` should make the compiler complain about `AbstractEntityDAO` not having generic paremeters.

Besides that your `AbstractEntityDAO()` constructor needs to accept a `Class` parameter as well. However, you don't need to pass the class as a parameter at all if you always use instances of classes with concrete types. Using reflection a class can determine the type of `T` if there is a concrete definition as in `EntityDAO`. The built-in reflection utilities provide no easy way to do this but fortunately you only need a little additional code to provide one, have a look here: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

That's basically what we're doing as well. Here's a rough rundown of our approach:

```
abstract class BaseDAO<T> {
  Class<?> entityClass;

  BaseDAO() {
    //this is based on the link I posted above but basically uses the actual concrete class 
    //(subclass determined by getClass() ) to extract the generic types and 
    //since we only have one we get the first one from the returned list
    entityClass = ReflectionHelper.getTypes(getClass(), BaseDAO.class).get(0); 
  }

  public T getEntity(Object id) { 
  ...
  }
}

abstract class TranslatableDAO<T extends TranslatableEntity> extends BaseDAO<T> {
...
}

//Users are not translatable
class UserDAO extends BaseDAO<User> {
...
}

//Products are translatable, i.e. Product extends TranslatableEntity
class ProductDAO extends TranslatableDAO<Product> {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I knew I was missing something!